# How to update related table MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables:  `orders, orders_history`.

```
orders
________
id | status

orders_history
id | order_id | status | user_id
```

The `orders_history` contains history of all  user's actions. At the same time `orders.status` contains the last status from `orders_history.status`.

I make these queries in transation:

```
transaction start
insert into orders_history...
$status = select status from order_history order by id desc limit 1;
update orders set status = $status where orders.id = id
```

My question is:

Should I use transaction and is it properly way to do that?
What if several transactions try to `insert, update` `orders_history` for the same `order_id`.

Comment: I think using a trigger can be better in this case

Comment: Consider removing the column `status` from `orders`. You can check the `status` of an order by querying the last (by some date column) `status` in `orders_history`.

Comment: I can not remove `orders.status` because I must have a terminated state of status whereas orders_history contains history of all status changes.

Comment: There's no context on the functionality of the *orders* table but it seems a *view* could easily replace this.

Comment: @AliceMessis What's the difference between the most recent `order_history.status` and the current `orders.status`? If they are always intended to be the same, then the solution offered by @forpas should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design pattern I might use in this case is...

Table 1:  History -- this is an audit trail of everything that has gone on.  (Think:  All the checks written and deposits made to a checking account.)

Table 2:  Current -- this is the current status of the information.  (Think, current account balance, status, etc.)

Whenever something happens (eg, a check clears):

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO History ...;
UPDATE Current ...;
COMMIT;
```

In the case of a checking account, something different is needed if your account is overdrawn, so let's make the transaction more complex:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT balance FROM Current WHERE acct = 123   FOR UPDATE;
if would be overdrawn then 
    email user
    UPDATE Current SET status = 'overdrawn' acct = 123;
    ...
else
    INSERT INTO History ...;
    UPDATE Current ...;
endif
COMMIT;
```

I prefer to put the "business logic" clearly in one place, not hidden in a Trigger.  (I might use a Trigger for monitoring or logging, but not for the main purpose of the tables.)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments above you could use a trigger to update the orders table -

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_order_status` AFTER INSERT ON `orders_history`
  FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE `orders` SET `status` = NEW.status WHERE id = NEW.order_id;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The better option would be to not store the redundant status in orders and just query for most recent status in orders_history.

```sql
SELECT orders.id, (SELECT status FROM orders_history oh WHERE orders.id = oh.order_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS status
FROM orders
```

Comment: And you can turn that query into a view.

Comment: The better option would be to not store the redundant status - why? It will be work faster that select all rows from table and filter them

Comment: @AliceMessis Redundant data risks inconsistency. I am unsure what you mean by `It will be work faster that select all rows from table and filter them`. The performance overhead is negligible with well written queries and appropriate indices in place. The best approach will be subject to lots of opinions. I assume the structures given for `orders` and `orders_history` are for illustrative purposes only. If `orders_history` is only tracking status changes then I would probably update orders and use trigger to populate the history.